# PyQt5 + Ubuntu (WSL) Desktop Application Development

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, wsl-2, vscode-remote

I have a problem. I am currently trying to work with **PyQt5 Desktop App** and I am using **WSL Ubuntu**. The Projects is already set-up and I am getting an error. I am also using **Vscode** as a text editor/ide.

**Error:**

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.

This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted
```

Solutions I have Made:

1. Reinstall PyQt5
2. pip uninstall opencv-python

   pip install opencv-python-headless
3. sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0
4. ```
   sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0
   ```

   **None of these solutions worked unfortunately**

**========================================================================**

**More Visualized Error Message**

[image]

**========================================================================**

**This is how my project looks like and my pip list:**

[image]

[image]

If anybody knows a work-around i will be glad with it.

An update, I added this to my script:
[image]

New Console Output:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Add `os.environ["QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS"] = "1"`

Comment: Hi I will be updating my question since i can not show you the output. But somehow I think this will make sense. Thanks for providing insights!

Comment: Have you been able to run any other GUI in your environment?
​

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

Comment: In wsl i have not tried it yet. As a solution, I am working with my Windows instead of wsl to run my PyQt5 GUI and it works very well. But somehow I am still figuring out how do I run GUI in my wsl ubuntu environment. Thank for the link!